# Updating/ disabling certain slider values dynamically in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, scheduling, slider

I am struggling with `Manipulate` dynamic updating. I would like to have an image containing two points which can both be moved in real time to any location on the image EXCEPT if the distance between them becomes smaller than a given value. 
The difficulty is that I do not want to be able to move them to a position where their distance is smaller than this value and then disable the sliders, like I have done below. I would like the slider to not enable me to go to the forbidden locations in the first place.
Please find my code below.

```
Manipulate[
 pt1 = {x1, y1};
 pt2 = {x2, y2};
 dist = N[EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]];
 Graphics[{Point[pt1], Point[pt1]}],
 {{x1, 0}, -5, 5, Enabled -> Dynamic[dist > 2]},
 {{y1, 0}, -5, 5, Enabled -> Dynamic[dist > 2]},
 {{x2, 2}, -5, 5, Enabled -> Dynamic[dist > 2]},
 {{y2, 2}, -5, 5, Enabled -> Dynamic[dist > 2]}]
```

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Ella

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[
  { pt1, pt2, dist
  , trackingFunction = Function[{val, sym}
    , If[Block[{sym = val}, dist >= 2], sym = val]
    , HoldRest
    ]
  }
, Manipulate[
    Graphics[{Point[Dynamic@pt1], Point[Dynamic@pt2]}
    , PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True
    ]

  , {{x1, 0}, -5, 5, TrackingFunction :> trackingFunction}
  , {{y1, 0}, -5, 5, TrackingFunction :> trackingFunction}
  , {{x2, 2}, -5, 5, TrackingFunction :> trackingFunction}
  , {{y2, 2}, -5, 5, TrackingFunction :> trackingFunction}

  , Initialization :> (
      pt1 := {x1, y1};  pt2 := {x2, y2}; dist := N[EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]];        
    )
  ]
]
```

Our `trackingFunction` checks whether `dist<0` and proceeds with update or not. Notice `Block` usage, we want to check without committing.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Btw, it feels better to use `Locators` instead of `Sliders`:

```
DynamicModule[ { pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2, 2}] }
, LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pts, If[EuclideanDistance @@ # > 2, pts = #] &]
  , Graphics[{Point[Dynamic[pts]]}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Super good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably too late, since kuba's answer has already been accepted, but I couldn't get his solution using a locator pane to work, so I'm posting my own more pedestrian version.

```
constraintF[q1_, q2_, pts_] :=
  Module[{p1, p2},
    {p1, p2} = pts;
    If[Norm[p2 - p1] >= 2,
      pts,
      If[q1 == p1,
        {q1, q1 + 2 Normalize[p2 - q1]},
        {q2, q2 + 2 Normalize[p1 - q2]}]]]

DynamicModule[{p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {2, 2}, q1, q2, pts},
  LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pts,
      {({q1, q2} = pts) &, ({p1, p2} = constraintF[q1, q2, #]) &, (pts = #) &}],
    Dynamic @ 
      Graphics[
        {{FaceForm[Transparent], Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]},
         {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{p1, p2}]}},
        Frame -> True],
    Appearance -> None],
  Initialization :> (pts = {p1, p2})]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: There was a typo so my LocatorPane should work now. Let me know if it still makes troubles for you.

Comment: @Kuba. Your corrected LocatorPane solution works, but on my computer it does not work nearly as smoothly as the code given above.